# Adding the same text value in a todo list

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am building a basic todo app in flutter. When I add a todo called "test", the todo gets added to the reorderable list. However, when I add another todo with the same name, the app crashes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: const TodoApp(),
    theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.yellow),
  ));
}

class TodoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<TodoApp> createState() => _TodoAppState();
}

class _TodoAppState extends State<TodoApp> {
  final _textyController = TextEditingController();
  List<String> storedText = [];
  List<bool> checkedValue = [];

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Todo"),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 15.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                //
                // LIST STARTS
                //

                child: ReorderableListView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  itemCount: storedText.length,
                  onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                        newIndex -= 1;
                      }
                      final String text = storedText.removeAt(oldIndex);
                      storedText.insert(newIndex, text);

                      final bool checked = checkedValue.removeAt(oldIndex);
                      checkedValue.insert(newIndex, checked);
                    });
                  },
                  //LEARN: UNDERSTAND THIS
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    //
                    //{STYLING} LIST TILE STARTS
                    //
                    return Padding(
                      key: ValueKey(storedText[index]),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.yellow),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          //
                          //LIST TILE STARTS
                          //
                          child: CheckboxListTile(
                              activeColor: Colors.black,
                              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                              //TODO: UNDERSTAND THIS
                              title: Text(storedText[index]),
                              value: checkedValue.isNotEmpty
                                  ? checkedValue[index]
                                  : false,
                              onChanged: (newCheckedValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  checkedValue[index] =
                                      newCheckedValue ?? false;
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _textyController,
                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      //LEARN: UNDERSTAND THIS
                      storedText.insert(0, value);
                      checkedValue.insert(0, false);
                      _textyController.clear();
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: '+ Add a task',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    focusColor: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  cursorColor: Colors.grey[400],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

I am guessing this is something to do with the key value being linked to the storedText name? Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Widget tree can not have duplicate keys, If you add same text, `itemBuilder` return duplicate keyItem from because of `key: ValueKey(storedText[index]),`

You can create a list of keys, I am using DateTime here.

```dart
  List<DateTime> keys = [];//state 

 ....
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  //
  //{STYLING} LIST TILE STARTS
  //
  return Padding(
    key: ValueKey(keys[index]),
```

And add key onSubmit

```dart
child: TextField(
  controller: _textyController,
  onSubmitted: (value) {
    setState(() {
      //LEARN: UNDERSTAND THIS
      keys.insert(0, DateTime.now());
```

I would prefer creating model class.

```dart
class Todo {
  final String text;
  final bool checked;
  final DateTime key;

  Todo({
    required this.text,
    required this.checked,
  }) : key = DateTime.now();
}
class TodoApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const TodoApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<TodoApp> createState() => _TodoAppState();
}


class _TodoAppState extends State<TodoApp> {
  final _textyController = TextEditingController();

  List<Todo> data = [];

  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Todo"),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 15.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                //
                // LIST STARTS
                //

                child: ReorderableListView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
                    setState(() {
                      if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
                        newIndex -= 1;
                      }
                      final Todo item = data.removeAt(oldIndex);
                      data.insert(newIndex, item);
                    });
                  },
                  //LEARN: UNDERSTAND THIS
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    //
                    //{STYLING} LIST TILE STARTS
                    //
                    return Padding(
                      key: ValueKey(data[index].key),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.yellow),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          //
                          //LIST TILE STARTS
                          //
                          child: CheckboxListTile(
                              activeColor: Colors.black,
                              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                              //TODO: UNDERSTAND THIS
                              title: Text(data[index].text),
                              value: data[index].checked,
                              onChanged: (newCheckedValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  data[index] = Todo(
                                    text: data[index].text,
                                    checked: newCheckedValue ?? false,
                                  );
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _textyController,
                  onSubmitted: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      //LEARN: UNDERSTAND THIS
                      data.insert(
                          0,
                          Todo(
                            text: value,
                            checked: false,
                          ));
                      _textyController.clear();
                    });
                  },
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: '+ Add a task',
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                    focusColor: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  cursorColor: Colors.grey[400],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```